# Unable to read file from s3 in lambda and use it in main handler function nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to build a json schema validator application in aws lambda using node js , here data is being stored in s3 as json .Schema is also stored in s3. I am unable to get the json data from s3 and use it for validation.
Here is the code for handler function .

```
exports.handler =async (event) =>{
   async function readfile(){ new AWS.S3().getObject(params, function(err, json_data)
    {
      if (!err) {
        const json = JSON.parse(new Buffer(json_data.Body).toString("utf8"));
console.log(json);
return json;
     }
   });
   }
   readfile();
   console.log(readfile());
   console.log(readfile().json);
   const validate = ajv.compile(userSchema);
    const valid = validate(readfile());
if (valid) {
  console.log('User data is valid');
   const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('User Data is valid!'),
    };
    return response;
} else {
  console.log('User data is INVALID!');
  console.log(validate.errors);
  const response = {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify('User Data is Invalid!')+JSON.stringify(validate.errors),
    };
 }
```

Comment: Quite a few issues here. The handler should not be both async and have a callback. You are calling readfile() repeatedly, unnecessarily. You are not awaiting the result of readfile(), so your result is a promise. Your readfile() function will never return the S3 data (your return statement is in the scope of the callback). You're not returning response in the not valid case. Use const/let rather than var. And you didn't tell us what was going wrong, or share any symptoms.

Comment: same happens with const also. can you please help in fixing  the code and paste there

Comment: 2020-05-13T23:21:18.110Z 4456adb8-4133-4923-ad4b-c7bd38150115 INFO Promise { undefined }
2020-05-13T23:21:18.169Z 4456adb8-4133-4923-ad4b-c7bd38150115 INFO undefined

Comment: @jarmod , please help on this

Answer (score 0):

a cleaner way to implement the code using await by enclosing the S3 client code in a try/catch block:

```
    try{
     const s3File = await new AWS.S3().getObject(params).promise();
     //process your file here
    }catch(e){
     console.log(e)
    }
```

Comment: but for getting content of file which param can i use .currenlty it is returning some value from s3 function call not the content

Comment: That should be `getObject(params).promise()`

Comment: This is fetching the data but in binary format .Do i need to encode it to utf-8 INFO {
  AcceptRanges: 'bytes',
  LastModified: 2020-05-14T00:05:13.000Z,
  ContentLength: 896,
  ETag: '"ae6cffb3ec94a137f39162efefa00882"',
  ContentType: 'application/json',
  Metadata: {},
  Body: <Buffer 7b 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 22 69 64 22 3a 20 36 34 32 30 39 36 39 30 2c 0d 0a 20 20 20 20 22 6e 61 6d 65 22 3a 20 22 4a 61 6e 65 20 53 6d 69 74 68 22 2c 0d ... 846 more bytes>
}

Comment: as per jarmod's comment, you need add .promise(). I updated the code. That will return the file and you can proceed processing it  as per your json file handling code.

Comment: good to know that. Maybe you can update the code to show how to handle the json file process. Could be useful for others that stumble upon this thread

Comment: i had to implement schema to get from dynamodb and use it there but unable to get value outside the function ``` const schemfromdb= await ddb.getItem(paramsdb,function(err, schemadata) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", schemadata.Item);
    return schemadata;
  }
}); ```

Comment: probably its best to post this as a new SO post. This thread is relevant to the your S3 api call issue

Answer (score 0):

> Working version of code

```
exports.handler =async (event,context) =>{
try{
     const s3File = await new AWS.S3().getObject(params).promise();
     const userda =s3File.Body.toString('utf8');
   //  console.log(userda);
   const validate = ajv.compile(userSchema);
    const valid = validate(JSON.parse(userda));
if (valid) {
  console.log('User data is valid');
   const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('User Data is valid!'),
    };
    return response;
} else {
  console.log('User data is INVALID!');
  console.log(validate.errors);
  const response = {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify('User Data is Invalid!')+JSON.stringify(validate.errors),
    };
    return response;
} }catch(e){
     console.log(e);
    }
} ;
```